# Updating Word Field Links From Excel on Sharepoint

Tags: excel, word, custom-field-types, sync

We are moving over to Sharepoint and use field links in our Word docs to update information passed in from a Spreadsheet.  If we want the links to work for multiple people they seem to have to be set up in Word as {LINK Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12 https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Folder/Workbook.xlsm "Worksheet!cellname" \a \t}.  The old method we used was the shared drive had a traditional file path. The issue we are running into is that on SharePoint these links act broken if we have the Workbook open.  The link must open the Workbook which is a considerably slower method of updating the links.  Additionally, then the Workbook goes into a Read Only state and can't be saved.  What are we able to do to get these links to work?

Comment: Please see: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-link-breaks-when-i-open-an-excel-file/984bb7c7-b3da-4a98-b2e3-248b9f29f7f1